# Questions on the derivation of Heron's formula for the area of a triangle in terms of its sides

Tags: triangles, area

Just for the fun of it,
I worked out
Heron's formula for the
area of a triangle
in terms of its sides,
$A
=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-c)(s-b)}$.
I've included it below.

In my
(and, I assume,
just about everybody's)
derivation,
the four terms
appear as sort of
algebraic coincidences,
and this made me wonder:

Is there a derivation
in which each term
has a geometric meaning?

Also,
the derivation begins
by choosing a particular side,
and ends up with
the well-known formula
which is symmetrical
on all the sides.
So, that brings to mind
this question:

Is there a derivation 
which is symmetrical
in all the sides
all the way through?

And those are my questions.

I'm fine with
this being a duplicate.

Here is my derivation.

Sides
$a, b, c$,
altitude $h$ on $c$.

$c$ divided into
$p$ and $c-p$.

Equations:

$a^2 = p^2+h^2,
b^2 
= (c-p)^2+h^2
= c^2-2cp+p^2+h^2
$.

$a^2-b^2
=2cp-c^2$
so
$p
=\dfrac{a^2-b^2+c^2}{2c}
$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
h^2
&=a^2-p^2\\
&=a^2-\dfrac{(a^2-b^2+c^2)^2}{(2c)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{(2ac)^2-(a^2-b^2+c^2)^2}{(2c)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{(2ac-(a^2-b^2+c^2))(2ac+(a^2-b^2+c^2))}{(2c)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{(b^2-(a^2-2ac+c^2))(-b^2+(a^2+2ac+c^2))}{(2c)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{(b^2-(a-c)^2)((a+c)^2-b^2)}{(2c)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{(b-(a-c))(b+(a-c))((a+c)-b)((a+c)+b)}{(2c)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{(b+c-a)(a+b-c)(a+c-b)(a+b+c)}{(2c)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{(a+b+c-2a)(a+b+c-2c)(a+b+c-2b)(a+b+c)}{(2c)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{(2s-2a)(2s-2c)(2s-2b)2s}{4c^2}
\qquad s=\dfrac{a+b+c}{2}\\
&=\dfrac{4(s-a)(s-c)(s-b)s}{c^2}\\
\text{so,}
&\text{ since } A = \dfrac{hc}{2},
A^2 = \dfrac{h^2c^2}{4}\\
A^2
&=s(s-a)(s-c)(s-b)\\
A
&=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-c)(s-b)}\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: I'm not sure, but please check whether [this](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMT668/EMAT6680.2000/Umberger/MATH7200/HeronFormulaProject/GeometricProof/geoproof.html) is useful.

Comment: That is nice, but complicated. It might be unreasonable to expect a simple proof considering the complexity of the result.